# Issues with URL open

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, url

I have problem with opening URLs. Sample:

- I open HexChat.
- I click on any URL.
- URL opens Chrome new window, but only new tab, no selected url.

This problem doesn't exist when I set Firefox/Opera as default browser. Also, **mailto** links works, they opens in Thunderbird.

Before this problem, I changed Google Chrome's settings in `alacarte`. I added `--enable-webgl` (I need WebGL for some games, Web lab and WebGL experiments) at end of line called *command* in `alacarte` (in Ubuntu `alacarte` is called *Main Menu*).

WebGL in Chrome works, but `xdg-open http://url.tld` doesn't. I reverted Chrome settings in `alacarte` to default. But **nothing**. Same problem.

**UPDATE:**
I tried to fix that with `dconf-editor`. **No changes.** Problem is same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to diagnose your problem is providing the content of Chrome launcher. The Chromium one is located in `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`, so check out that folder for the Chrome launcher. It may be a relatively large file, so it may be better to use `cat /path/to/google-chrome.desktop | pastebinit`.

Comment: I don't know where is that chrome launcher. Problem isn't launcher, I don't have launcher. I have Chrome in Unity Launcher (on left).

Comment: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/y88TvI8mejHyt2ZoVyJc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used alacarte to simulate what you did and it seems it saves the modified .desktop on `~/.local/share/applications`.

So to undo the changes you made just navigate to that folder and delete the Chrome launcher. This is a local version which is checked before the system wide .desktop, so if you remove it you will have still how to launch Chrome. If the Chrome icon on launcher stops working just remove it (left click -> "Unlock from Launcher") and add it again.

Also you can try to inspect that file and see what is wrong. I would guess you either forgot one field code (see [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html)) or you are not escaping well something.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, that work! Local share version was problem! Thanks! Now solved. :)